# Processing an Akka Stream with a One-Time Header

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have an application which receives a TCP socket connection which will send data in the form:

`n{json}bbbbbbbbbb...`

where `n` is the length of the following `json` in bytes, and the `json` might be something like `{'splitEvery': 5}`, which will dictate how I break up and process the potentially infinite string of bytes to follow.

I want to process this stream with Akka in Scala. I *think* `streams` are the right tool for this, but I am having a hard time finding an example that uses streams with distinct processing stages. Most stream flows seem to do the same thing over and over, like the `prefixAndTail` example [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20008). That is very close to how I want to process the `n{json}` part of my stream, but the difference is I only need to do this **once** per connection and then move on to a different "stage" of processing.

Can anyone point me to an example of using Akka streams with distinct stages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `GraphStage` which processes a stream of `ByteString`s:

- Extract chunk size from header
- Emit `ByteString`s of the specified chunk size

```scala
import akka.stream.{Attributes, FlowShape, Inlet, Outlet}
import akka.stream.stage.{GraphStage, GraphStageLogic, InHandler, OutHandler}
import akka.util.ByteString

class PreProcessor extends GraphStage[FlowShape[ByteString, ByteString]] {

  val in: Inlet[ByteString] = Inlet("ParseHeader.in")
  val out: Outlet[ByteString] = Outlet("ParseHeader.out")

  override val shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {

      var buffer = ByteString.empty
      var chunkSize: Option[Int] = None
      private var upstreamFinished = false

      private val headerPattern = """^\d+\{"splitEvery": (\d+)\}""".r

      /**
        * @param data The data to parse.
        * @return The chunk size and header size if the header
        * could be parsed.
        */
      def parseHeader(data: ByteString): Option[(Int, Int)] =
      headerPattern.
        findFirstMatchIn(data.decodeString("UTF-8")).
        map { mtch => (mtch.group(1).toInt, mtch.end) }

      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          if (isClosed(in)) emit()
          else pull(in)
        }
      })

      setHandler(in, new InHandler {
        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          val elem = grab(in)
          buffer ++= elem
          if (chunkSize.isEmpty) {
            parseHeader(buffer) foreach { case (chunk, headerSize) =>
              chunkSize = Some(chunk)
              buffer = buffer.drop(headerSize)
            }
          }
          emit()
        }

        override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
          upstreamFinished = true
          if (chunkSize.isEmpty || buffer.isEmpty) completeStage()
          else {
            if (isAvailable(out)) emit()
          }
        }
      })

      private def continue(): Unit =
        if (isClosed(in)) completeStage()
        else pull(in)

      private def emit(): Unit = {
        chunkSize match {
          case None => continue()
          case Some(size) =>
            if (upstreamFinished && buffer.isEmpty ||
               !upstreamFinished && buffer.size < size) {
              continue()
            } else {
              val (chunk, nextBuffer) = buffer.splitAt(size)
              buffer = nextBuffer
              push(out, chunk)
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And the test case to illustrate the usage:

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import akka.util.ByteString
import org.scalatest._

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

class PreProcessorSpec extends FlatSpec {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Test")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val random = new Random

  "" should "" in {

    def splitRandom(s: String, n: Int): List[String] = s match {
      case "" => Nil
      case s =>
        val (head, tail) = s splitAt random.nextInt(n)
        head :: splitRandom(tail, n)
    }

    val input = """17{"splitEvery": 5}aaaaabbbbbcccccddd"""

    val strings = splitRandom(input, 7)
    println(strings.map(s => s"[$s]").mkString(" ") + "\n")

    val future = Source.fromIterator(() => strings.iterator).
      map(ByteString(_)).
      via(new PreProcessor()).
      map(_.decodeString("UTF-8")).
      runForeach(println)

    Await.result(future, 5 seconds)
  }

}
```

Example output:

```
[17{"] [splitE] [very"] [] [: 5}] [aaaaa] [bbb] [bbcccc] [] [cddd]

aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddd
```

Comment: I like this, very clean and explicit. There's a lot in here for me to chew on... a great learning example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the chunk size depends on the content of the stream, but all processing stages have to be materialized before the stream data is processed, you can't easily use a convenient method like `Source.group(chunkSize)`. I would suggest to strip the metadata from the beginning of the stream (using a different approach than Akka streams) and feed the rest of the stream into `Source.group(chunkSize)`.

Alternatively you could fold/scan the stream using a state machine, but this is much more cumbersome:

```scala
implicit val system = ActorSystem("Test")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val input = """17{"splitEvery": 5}aaaaabbbbbccccc"""

def getChunkSize(json: String) = 5 // dummy implementation

sealed trait State
case class GetLength(number: String) extends State
case class GetJson(n: Int, json: String) extends State
case class ProcessData(chunkSize: Int, s: String) extends State

type Out = (State, Option[String])

val future = Source.fromIterator(() => input.iterator).
  scan[Out]((GetLength(""), None)) {
    case ((GetLength(s), _), e) if e.isDigit => (GetLength(s + e), None)
    case ((GetLength(s), _), e) => (GetJson(s.toInt - 1, e.toString), None)
    case ((GetJson(0, json), _), e) => (ProcessData(getChunkSize(json), e.toString), None)
    case ((GetJson(n, json), _), e) => (GetJson(n - 1, json + e), None)
    case ((ProcessData(chunkSize, s), _), e) if s.length == chunkSize - 1 => (ProcessData(chunkSize, ""), Some(s + e))
    case ((ProcessData(chunkSize, s), _), e) => (ProcessData(chunkSize, s + e), None)
  }.
  collect { case (_, Some(s)) => s }.
  runForeach(println)

println(Await.result(future, 1 second))

// aaaaa
// bbbbb
// ccccc
```

---

For the record, here's an approach that won't work since `takeWhile` consumes the next element of the iterator (when `_.isDigit` fails), which is still needed for the subsequent JSON parsing stage:

```scala
val it = input.iterator
def nextSource = Source.fromIterator(() => it)

implicit class Stringify[+Out, +Mat](val source: Source[Out, Mat]) {
  def stringify = source.runFold("")(_ + _)
}

val future2 = nextSource.
  takeWhile(_.isDigit).
  stringify.
  map(_.toInt).
  map { l =>
    nextSource.
      take(l).
      stringify.
      map(getChunkSize).
      map { chunkSize =>
        nextSource.
          grouped(chunkSize).
          map(_.mkString).
          runForeach(println)
      }
  }

println(Await.result(future2, 1 second))

// aaaab
// bbbbc
// cccc
```

Comment: Thank you! You suggested parsing the first bits off without using `streams` and then passing the rest into a `Source`. I'm referencing the `server` part of this TcpEcho example for TCP streaming (http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/akka-stream-scala#code/src/main/scala/sample/stream/TcpEcho.scala), and this example for TCP with Actors (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9-RC2/scala/io-tcp.html#io-scala-tcp), but I'm still not sure how to, say, start with the Actor receiving and then pass the open connection to a Source.

Comment: In other words, without sounding ungrateful (because this is already really useful!) you gave one example of the "cumbersome" method and one example of a method that won't work. Could you add an example of your suggested method?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information; when you are implementing a TCP server it is not possible to extract and strip the header without buffering. I added another answer with a `GraphStage` implementation, which is probably the most 'Akka-ish' approach.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to handle a 2-byte length header followed by data. This may help with the logic of handling/accumulating data based on the length prefix using GraphStage. Used various akka docs online and the idea presented in the solution provided earlier to implement it in java.

Java code

```
package com.example;

import akka.Done;
import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors;
import akka.stream.*;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;
import akka.stream.stage.GraphStage;
import akka.stream.stage.GraphStageLogic;
import akka.stream.stage.InHandler;
import akka.stream.stage.OutHandler;
import akka.util.ByteString;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

//import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink;

public class TwoByteLengthFramingFlow extends GraphStage<FlowShape<ByteString, ByteString>> {
    private final Inlet<ByteString> inlet = Inlet.create("TwoByteLengthFraming.in");
    private final Outlet<ByteString> outlet = Outlet.create("TwoByteLengthFraming.out");
    FlowShape<ByteString, ByteString> shape = FlowShape.of(inlet, outlet);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create(Behaviors.empty(), "Blah");
        byte[] b0 = {0, 4, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 0}; // The last 0 to simulate incomplete length in packet 1
        byte[] b1 = {4, 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'A',9};// the last 9 is to simulate stream end but graphstage has one byte in the buffer (simulating incomplete message)

        ByteString x0 = ByteString.fromArray(b0);
        ByteString x1 = ByteString.fromArray(b1);
        List<ByteString> l = new ArrayList<>();
        // simulate messages as tcp streams where data is coming in and we need assemble the message from the packets.
        l.add(x0);
        l.add(x1);

        // ByteString[] b =
        // {ByteString.fromArray({0x0}])'A','B','C','D',0,4,'E','F','G'};
        Graph<FlowShape<ByteString, ByteString>, NotUsed> flowgraph = new TwoByteLengthFramingFlow();
        Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> flow = Flow.fromGraph(flowgraph);
        Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<Done>> printSink = Sink.foreach(msg -> System.out.println(msg.utf8String()));

        Source.from(l)
              .via(flow)
              .to(printSink)
              .run(system);


        // Just to see what happens when the sink cancelled terminates the flow
//        Source.from(l)
//              .via(flow)
//              .to(Sink.cancelled())
//              .run(system);
    }

    Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> getFlow() {
        Graph<FlowShape<ByteString, ByteString>, NotUsed> flowgraph = new TwoByteLengthFramingFlow();
        Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> flow = Flow.fromGraph(flowgraph);
        return flow;
    }

    @Override
    public FlowShape<ByteString, ByteString> shape() {

        return shape;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphStageLogic createLogic(Attributes inheritedAttributes) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new GraphStageLogicExtension(shape);
    }

    private final class GraphStageLogicExtension extends GraphStageLogic {

        private final List<ByteString> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        protected ByteString buffer = ByteString.emptyByteString();

        private GraphStageLogicExtension(Shape shape) {
            super(shape);

            setHandler(inlet, new InHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onPush() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("onPush()");
                    // upstream pushed data, our onPush got called
                    // All incoming bytes are added to the buffer. We concat as there may incomplete messages in the bugger
                    buffer = buffer.concat(grab(inlet));
                    // recursively extract as many messages as you can [len+message+len+message....]
                    // Extract the messages you can and data can remain in the buffer. If you cannot extract len+data as all the bytes aren't available (either 2 bytes of length aren't available
                    // or 2 bytes of length are available but the  equivalent data for that length is not available
                    // , append that into the buffer and extract what you can. The net time data arrives it will get added to the buffer and we can try again.
                    extractMessages();
                    // emit extracted messages
                    emitChunk();

                    //
                    //pull(inlet);

                }

                @Override
                public void onUpstreamFinish() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("onUpstreamFinish()");
                    // upstream signalled its done
                    if (buffer.size() == 0 && messages.size() == 0) {
                        // no incomplete message in buffer
                        completeStage();
                    }
                    else {
                        // There are elements left in buffer, so
                        // we keep accepting downstream pulls and push from buffer until emptied.
                        //
                        // It might be though, that the upstream finished while it was pulled, in which
                        // case we will not get an onPull from the downstream, because we already had one.
                        // In that case we need to emit from the buffer.
                        if (isAvailable(outlet))
                            emitChunk();
                    }


                }

                private void emitChunk() {
                    System.out.println("emitChunk()");
                    // If we don't have extracted messaged
                    if (messages.size() <= 0) {
                        // if the upstream closed the inlet, we are done
                        if (isClosed(inlet)) {
                            completeStage();
                        }
                        // we can pull to get more data
                        else {
                            System.out.println("pull()");
                            pull(inlet);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // we have messages so send one and remove it from the list.
                        System.out.println("emit()");
                        emit(outlet, messages.remove(0));
                    }
                }
            });

            setHandler(outlet, new OutHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onPull() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("onPull()");
                    //downstream pulled so we got onPull
                    if (messages.size() > 0) {
                        // if we have messages we can push them
                        System.out.println("push()");
                        push(outlet, messages.remove(0));
                    }
                    else
                        // if we don't have messages to push, we need more dta from upstream, we will do a pull and upstream can react to it and push data and our onPush will get called
                        System.out.println("pull()");
                    pull(inlet);

                }

                @Override
                public void onDownstreamFinish() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Downstream  Finished");
                    OutHandler.super.onDownstreamFinish();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void extractMessages() {

            Tuple2<ByteString, ByteString> lengthDataTuple = buffer.splitAt(2);
            int messageLength = getLength(lengthDataTuple._1);
            if ((messageLength < 0) || (lengthDataTuple._2.take(messageLength)
                                                          .size() != messageLength)) {
                return;

            }
            if (messageLength == 0) {
                //maybe its a 0 byte ping message. Let the next stage handle empty bytestring.
                messages.add(ByteString.emptyByteString());
            }
            else {
                messages.add(lengthDataTuple._2.take(messageLength));
            }
            //Update buffer by removing messages that could be extracted
            buffer = buffer.drop(2 + messageLength);
            // recurse, till we can extract whatever is possible
            extractMessages();

        }

        private int getLength(ByteString header) {
/*
If length was
255 = 0xFF : b[0] = 0xff b[1] = 0x00,
256 = 0x100 : b[0] = 0x00 b[1] = 0x01,
257= 0x101 : b[0] = 0x01 b[1] = 0x01

Basically length div 256 is in b[1] and length mod 256 is in b[0]
 */
            byte[] b = header.toArray();
            if (b.length == 2) {
                return (((b[0]) & 0xFF) << 8) | ((b[1]) & 0xFF);
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```